# Resolving audio broadcasting error: client join failed DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED (Agora.io)

Tags: agora.io

I'm a server side developer with rudimentary JS knowhow. I'm tinkering with Agora's audio broadcasting functionality (specifically for the web). For reference, I've been following this: https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/start_live_audio_web?platform=Web

I'm attempting to broadcast audio as a `host`. I have an HTML button which fires a JS function where I:

- Initialize a client
- Set the role
- Join a predefined channel
- Publish a local stream

My understanding is that accomplshing the aforementioned will enable me to broadcast audio. When I try this, I end up getting a `client join failed DYNAMIC_KEY_EXPIRED` error. I'm unable to find documentation regarding how to resolve this. Can you help me resolve this? An illustrative example would be nice.

My JS code is below. Note that I'm using a temp token to test this functionality on localhost.

```js
    // rtc object
    var rtc = {
      client: null,
      joined: false,
      published: false,
      localStream: null,
      remoteStreams: [],
      params: {}
    };

    // Options for joining a channel
    var option = {
      appID: "anAppID",// from 'Project Management' dashboard
      channel: "AudioLive",
      uid: null,//The user ID should be unique in a channel. If you set the user ID as null or 0, the Agora server assigns a user ID and returns it in the onSuccess callback.
      token: "aTempToken"// TEMP Token
    }
    
    function createBroadcast(role) {

        console.log("entered createBroadcast");
        
        // Create a client
        rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: "live", codec: "h264"});

        // Initialize the client
        rtc.client.init(option.appID, function () {
            console.log("init success");

            // Note: in a live broadcast, only the host can be heard and seen. You can also call setClientRole() to change the user role after joining a channel.
            rtc.client.setClientRole(role);
            console.log("role is set");

            // Call Client.join in the onSuccess callback of Client.init
            rtc.client.join(option.token ? option.token : null, option.channel, option.uid ? +option.uid : null, function (uid) {
                console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
                rtc.params.uid = uid;

                // Call AgoraRTC.createStream to create a stream in the onSuccess callback of Client.join
                rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
                    streamID: rtc.params.uid,
                    audio: true,
                    video: false,
                    screen: false,
                })

                // Call Stream.init to initialize the stream after 'creating' the stream above
                // Initialize the local stream
                rtc.localStream.init(function () {
                    
                    console.log("init local stream success");
                    
                    // play stream with html element id "local_stream"
                    rtc.localStream.play("local_stream");

                    // Call Client.publish in the onSuccess callback of Stream.init to publish the local stream
                    // Publish the local stream
                    rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
                      console.log("publish failed");
                      console.error(err);
                    })

                }, function (err) {
                  console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
                });


              }, function(err) {
                console.error("client join failed", err)
            })

          }, (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

```html
<div style="background:#f0f3f4;padding:20px">
    <button id="broadast" style="height:40px;width:200px" onclick="createBroadcast('host')">Start Live Broadcast</button>
</div>
```

I've not added the actual values for `appID` and `token` in the code above.

Note: Please ask for more information in case you require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you are facing is due to the expiry of the token generated for authentication purposes while generating an APP ID. To resolve this you will have to generate a new token as elaborated in the below given links:

[Token-expired](https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/token_error#1091182-token-expired) 
[renewToken](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#renewtoken)

A token (or a temporary token) expires after a certain period of time. When the SDK notifies the client that the token is about to expire or has expired by the **onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire** or **onTokenPrivilegeDidExpire** callbacks, you need to generate a new token and call the **renewToken** method.

```
client.on("onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire", function(){
//After requesting a new token
client.renewToken(token);
});
```

```
client.on("onTokenPrivilegeDidExpire", function(){
//After requesting a new token
client.renewToken(token);
});
```

Include the above functions in your javascript code along with the rest of the eventListeners.
Incase your application doesn't require security you can opt to not use a token and generate an App ID without a certificate. 
[App ID without certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgoaM.png)

Do get back for further support incase the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Well all this still be applicable if one is trying to use a temp token for testing over localhost?

Comment: If you are using a temporary token, you can simply generate a new one from the dashboard if it expires. Of course in the long run you should use a token server for production instead of a temporary token.